# Foreach Loop Is Not Executing

Tags: c#

There was a similar type of solution I found and I tried to follow-up but still I failed to solve.

I have created a student class with public property First_Name & Last_Name.
then using Arraylist I wanted to get & print the details of each student. But after executing the code what I got is empty console window. When I run the code using breakpoint I saw that flow of code is not entering into the foreach loop. Please Help me....

```
ArrayList studentList = new ArrayList();

    public void getStudent()
    {
        foreach (Student student in studentList)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter Your First Name: ");
            student.First_Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter Your Last Name: ");
            student.Last_Name = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public void printStudentInformation()
    {
        foreach (Student student in studentList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Name Of The Student Is {0} {1}", student.First_Name, student.Last_Name);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code that calls `getStudent()`?  Where is the code that calls `printStudentInformation()`?  Where is the code that adds students to the `studentList` array?  You may find this useful: [Advice on debugging small programs.](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You appear to have no students in your `studentList`.

Comment: if you are calling properly and it's not entering the loop that just means your list empty.

Comment: If both are working consider one as answer

Comment: Sorry actually I am little bit new here....Suji

Answer (score 1):

When you run the code for first time there is no student in `studentList` and `foreach` in `getStudent` won't be executed. Create new instance of `Student` class then store `FirstName` and `LastName` in student object and add student object to `studentList` array.

```
public void getStudent()
{
    var student = new Student();

    Console.Write("Enter Your First Name: ");
    student.First_Name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter Your Last Name: ");
    student.Last_Name = Console.ReadLine();

   studentList.Add(student);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using `foreach` for displaying values you have to populate the list. for that you can use the following code. then apply your for each for displaying the content. hence the method signature have to be changed as follows:

```
public void getStudent()
    {
      List<Student> StudentList = new List<Student>();
      string nextVal = "y";
      while (nextVal == "N")
        {
           var student = new Student();
           Console.Write("Enter Your First Name: ");
           student.First_Name = Console.ReadLine();
           Console.Write("Enter Your Last Name: ");
           student.Last_Name = Console.ReadLine();
           StudentList.Add(student);
           Console.Write("Do you wnat to add more data(Y/N)");
           nextVal = Console.ReadKey().ToString();
        }
  }
```